# Finding Function Names In An Executable's Address Space

Tags: linux, debugging, executable, memory-address, instructions

Given a list of assembly instructions that were executed (and their relevant addresses), I need to figure out the name of the functions of which they belong. I can imagine that I need to compile the program with debugging symbols  but I don't know how to proceed past this point.

For example, if I have the following:

```
ffffffff8106b388 718373092536 other insn: 4d 8b af a0 03 00 00
ffffffff8106b38f 718373092536 other insn: 49 8d 45 68
ffffffff8106b393 718373092536 other insn: 48 89 45 c8
ffffffff8106b397 718373092536 other insn: 41 0f 0d 4d 68
ffffffff8106b39c 718373092536 other insn: 8b 0d 5e bc 09 01
ffffffff8106b3a2 718373092536 other insn: 85 c9
```

I would want to know that the first instruction pertains to, lets say, the 15th line of main().

Thoughts?

Comment: look at code of gdb, as I remember you can type `li *0xADDRESS_OF_MEMORY_HEX` and it print corresponding function and its source code.

Comment: Although this answers the question, are you aware of a any straightforward method that can extract this information on a larger scale? For example, instead of just wanting to know the function names of a few instructions, I would want to know the function names of, lets say, 5000 instructions.

Comment: gdb have API, also it have embedded languages, one of them is python. So automate any task will be very simple.